# PyTorch multiprocessing with CUDA sets tensors to 0

Tags: multithreading, pytorch

The following code works perfectly on CPU. On CUDA, the second print shows that the weights are all 0.

If I don't pass `l` to the pool, it works. If I replace the pool from `concurrent.futures` to `mp.Process` weights are still 0.

This happens only on CUDA.

What am I doing wrong?

Python 3.10.9
PyTorch 2.0.0
CUDA 11.7

```py
import torch
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from torch import multiprocessing as mp

def goo(l):
    return l(torch.rand(2, device='cuda'))

def run():
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')

    l = torch.nn.Linear(2, 2).to('cuda').share_memory()
    print(vars(l))

    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(1, mp_context=ctx)
    pool.submit(goo, l)

    def foo():
        print(vars(l))

    thread = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    thread.submit(foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```